# Search people by alphabet characters in TypeScipt?

Tags: arrays, typescript, react-native, react-typescript

How to  create a search bar for a list of strings and filter content by alphabet character from TextInput component?
The search bar must works by updating the search state each time text is entered or changed in the text field.

```
const alphabetCharacters: string[] = [
    'A',
    'B',
    'C',
    'D',
    'E',
    'F',
    'G',
    'H',
    'I',
    'J',
    'K',
    'L',
    'M',
    'N',
    'O',
    'P',
    'Q',
    'R',
    'S',
    'T',
    'U',
    'V',
    'W',
    'X',
    'Y',
    'Z',
    '#',
];

const searchPeople = () => {
    
};

<TextInput
                    onChange={searchPeople}
                    value=''
                    placeholder='Typ een voornaam'
                    keyboardType='default'
                    returnKeyType='done'
                    newDesign={true}
                />
```

Comment: Awesome! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you asking what the `searchPeople` function should look like, or something else? Please be more specific with what you need help with